# expression expected and what parameter i need to use

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

There is problem when i use hide (Page_aboutus) .it said that expression expected ,so what parameter i need to use here. 
. In addition, i write below  code. My code is on replacefragment() function to show and hide fragment.Inside Hide() function block i don't know how to describe the current fragment.

```
public class Page_Aboutus extends Fragment {
    View purview;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        purview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page__aboutus, container, false);
        final RelativeLayout relate = (RelativeLayout) purview.findViewById(R.id.relate);
        final LinearLayout open_liu = (LinearLayout) purview.findViewById(R.id.open_liu);
        final LinearLayout open_zhen = (LinearLayout) purview.findViewById(R.id.open_zhen);
        final LinearLayout open_chen = (LinearLayout) purview.findViewById(R.id.open_chen);
        final LinearLayout open_wang = (LinearLayout) purview.findViewById(R.id.open_wang);
        open_liu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment fragment = new Liu();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
            }
        });
        open_zhen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                fragment = new Liuzhen();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
            }
        });
        open_chen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                fragment = new Chengyixuan();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
            }
        });
        open_wang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                fragment = new wanglei();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
            }
        });
        return purview;
    }



    public void replaceFragment(Fragment somefragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, somefragment)
                .hide(Page_Aboutus)//error here;
        transaction.addToBackStack("2");
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with the error you get please?

Comment: Page_aboutus    underline in red (expression expected)

Comment: And what is the error message you get at runtime ?

Comment: Change this hide(Page_Aboutus); to hide(this);

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you're using the following:

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, somefragment)
           .hide(Page_Aboutus);
```

you're giving a class name but the `hide()` method needs a fragment as the parameter.

If you want to hide the current fragment, you can use `this`. Something like this:

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, somefragment)
           .hide(this);
```